# function for an unordered array to sort numbers numerically?

Tags: php, arrays, ruby, sorting

Can you make a function for an unordered array to sort numbers numerically? It can be in Ruby or a simple Pseudocode.

```
$unordedNumbersArray = array(10, 35, 11, 250, 48);
```

My answer was:

```
sort($unordedNumbersArray);    
$clength = count($unordedNumbersArray);
for($x = 0; $x < $clength; $x++) {
    echo $unordedNumbersArray[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

But it was not accepted, because my senior developer is trying to find my programming style. I can not use `sort()` or any similar function.

Can someone please explain, or show an example, on how to sort out this kind of task, please!

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.toptal.com/developers/sorting-algorithms

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]", "[mcve]" and the linked pages. Your question is too broad. You're asking for us to write code in either PHP or Ruby, or explain code written in PHP or Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Please have a look into this [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)

```
$unordedNumbersArray = array(10, 35, 11, 250, 48);

$clength = count($unordedNumbersArray);
for ($x = 0; $x < $clength; $x++) {
    for ($y = $x + 1; $y < $clength - 1; $y++) {
        if ($unordedNumbersArray[$x] > $unordedNumbersArray[$y]) {
            $temp = $unordedNumbersArray[$x];
            $unordedNumbersArray[$x] = $unordedNumbersArray[$y];
            $unordedNumbersArray[$y] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
var_dump($unordedNumbersArray);
```

Output:

```
array(5) { [0]=> int(10) [1]=> int(11) [2]=> int(35) [3]=> int(48) [4]=> int(250) }
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain what a Bubble Sort is while you are at it.

Comment: thankyou @engineersmnky for your support. i appreciate you as you are supporting new user. keep it up :)

Answer (score 2):

You can sort in O(n) using `counting sort` if numbers in array is in range(0,10^6) Otherwise you have to use bubblesort O(n^2) or mergesort O(nlogn)

Counting sort Algorithm in ruby:

```
arr = [10, 35, 11, 250, 48]
sorted_arr = []
arr_hash = {}
arr.map{|element| arr_hash[element] = 1}
(0..1000000).each do |n|
  sorted_arr << n if arr_hash[n]
end
puts sorted_arr
```

Comment: counting sort can be constrained more than that by pulling min and max from the original array. While it does require an additional loop it would probably be faster than looping through 10^6 elements.

Comment: how will you find min and max in array, in worst case of array size of 10^6, you will waste one loop finding min and max of array, consider worst case analysis not the best cases

Comment: consider all cases especially when given an Array. perform on best cases and handle the worst. currently you are assuming the worst not considering it

Comment: agree, we could check array size and decide whether to find min and max or not @engineersmnky

Comment: Agreed only other thing one might mention is that this implementation of count sorting assumes a single occurrence of each `n`